# Returning an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this function:

```
buildDeck = () => {
    let suit = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S'];
    let rank = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
    let deck = [];
    for (var i=0; i < rank.length; i++){
      for (var k=0; k < suit.length; k++){
        deck.push(rank[i] + suit[k])
      }
    };
    return deck;
  }
```

this returns me an array like `['2C', '4D', etc]`
I would like it to return me an array of objects so inside each one is:
suit: 'C', rank: 4 for example
How can I convert an array of strings into an array of objects with the rank and suit being a property within each object?

Comment: `deck.push({ suit: suit[k], rank: rank[i] })`

Comment: *"How can I convert an array of strings into an array of objects..."* Don't. Create the array of objects in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
buildDeck = () => {
    let suit = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S'];
    let rank = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];
    let deck = [];
    for (var i=0; i < rank.length; i++){
      for (var k=0; k < suit.length; k++){
        deck.push({ rank: rank[i], suit: suit[k]})
      }
    };
    return deck;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the arrow functions as well for the ranks and suits.

```js
var buildDeck = deck =>
        [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14].forEach(rank =>
            ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S'].forEach(suit =>
                deck.push({rank, suit}))),
    deck = [];

buildDeck(deck)
console.log(deck);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Or use a generator

```js
function* buildDeck() {
    for (let rank of [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]) {
        for (let suit of ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S']) {
            yield {rank, suit};
        };
    };
}

var deck = [...buildDeck()];
console.log(deck);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Totally unreadable code, my dear. I think he was looking for a quick, simple solution.

Comment: Looks like an interesting solution. It does seem somewhat like a "clever" solution and would probably be tricky to read for anyone who needs to ask how to do this in the first place, but looking at it, it's actually pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

Run two nested maps over suits and ranks, building a nested array of the little suit/rank objects, then flatten with `concat(...`.

```js
const buildDeck = () => {
  let suits = ['C', 'D', 'H', 'S'];
  let ranks = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14];

  return [].concat(...suits.map(suit => ranks.map(rank =>({suit, rank}))));
}

console.log(buildDeck());
```

Comment: nice idea with concat to flatten the arrays.